# Linq query on DataTable

Tags: linq, datatable

I have a DataTable that is filled from a stored procedure. I am doing a query on the DataTable using a groupby so that I can implement a ListView within a ListView. (Matt Berseth - [Building a Grouping Grid with the ASP.NET 3.5 LinqDataSource and ListView Controls](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html))

My Query in my codebehind:

```
var query = from c in dtTaskOrder.AsEnumerable() 
        group c by c.Field<string>("CLIN") into g
        select new
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count(),
            Items = g
        };

listv.DataSource = query.ToList();
listv.DataBind();
```

In my aspx file I am trying to Eval on the Items and the subsequent columns:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv1" ... DataSource='<%# Eval("Items") %>'>

   <td><%# Eval("SLIN") %></td> // column name
   <td><%# Eval("ACRN") %></td> // column name
   <td><%# Eval("Status") %></td> // last column name
```

The HttpException was unhandled by user code - when it tries to Eval on the above column names.

How can I formulate the above query so that "Items" is "Typed" and I can use the column names.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not just the typo, you could use a subquery on `g` to build a collection of strongly-typed objects:

```
var query = from c in dtTaskOrder.AsEnumerable()
            group c by c.Field("CLIN") into g
            select new
            {
                Key = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count(),
                Items = from i in g
                        select new { CLIN = i.Field("CLIN"),
                                     ACRN = i.Field("ACRN"),
                                     Status = i.Field("Status") }
            };
```

Comment: Thanks dahlbyk. The subquery on g did it. 
I was able to Eval on the columns because it new about the column names. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the Eval("SLIN") you wrote is supposed to be Eval("CLIN") ? 
just a thought. Otherwise,i used the same code before and it works.